# How do I specify task key name containing spaces?

Tags: sbt

I have this output from SBT:

`[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last connect-userdata/*:Extra environment variables to set in the docker image for the full output.`

Sure, it won't accept:

`last connect-userdata/*:Extra environment variables to set in the docker image`

The task is defined like that:

`lazy val dockerExtraEnv = TaskKey[Seq[(String, String)]]("Extra environment variables to set in the docker image")`

So how do I get the detailed output?

Answer (score 2):

`TaskKey` takes a name of the task and an optional description. So I think you passed description as the name. What you probably wanted to do instead is to use the `taskKey` macro which will use the value identifier as the task name:

```
lazy val dockerExtraEnv = taskKey[Seq[(String, String)]]("Extra environment variables to set in the docker image")
```

This is the same as

```
lazy val dockerExtraEnv = TaskKey[Seq[(String, String)]]("dockerExtraEnv", "Extra environment variables to set in the docker image")
```

where `dockerExtraEnv` is the name of the task.